# Laravel-mix + Vue Ленивая загрузка

Tags: laravel, vue.js, frontend, lazyloading, laravel-mix

Уже 6 день бьюсь над тем чтобы добавить к проекту ленивую загрузку компонентов. Пожалуйста, кто уже сталкивался с такой необходимостью, поделитесь опытом, наработками или подсказками в это области, прошу. А то я скоро брошу этот фронт и улечу в космос на своем горящем стуле(

.babelrc (лежит в корне проекта):

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
      "useBuiltIns": false
    }]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
  ]
}
```

package.json:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.1.6",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.1.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.0-beta.0",
        "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
        "browser-sync": "^2.24.7",
        "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.2",
        "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
        "laravel-mix": "^2.1.14"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
        "filepond-plugin-file-validate-type": "^1.1.0",
        "filepond-plugin-image-preview": "^1.1.0",
        "fullpage.js": "^3.0.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.10",
        "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
        "parallax-js": "^3.1.0",
        "simplex-noise": "^2.4.0",
        "three": "^0.96.0",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-awesome-swiper": "^3.1.3",
        "vue-carousel": "^0.14.0",
        "vue-filepond": "^2.1.6",
        "vue-lory": "0.0.5",
        "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
        "vuetify": "^1.1.4",
        "vuex": "^3.0.1"
    }
}
```

Код компонента:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const Home = () => import('../views/client/Home');
// const AboutUs = () => import('../views/client/AboutUs');
// const Contacts = () => import('../views/client/Contacts');
// const Portfolio = () => import('../views/client/Portfolio');

//components
// import Home from '../views/client/Home';
import AboutUs from '../views/client/AboutUs';
import Contacts from '../views/client/Contacts';
import Portfolio from '../views/client/Portfolio';

import {bus} from '../app'

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        component: Home,
        name: 'home',
        beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
            window.onload= function(){
                document.getElementById("WebGL-output").style.opacity = "1";
            };
            next();
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/about-us',
        component: AboutUs,
        name: 'about-us',
        beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
            window.onload= function(){
                window.dispatchEvent(new Event("bubbelMoveRight"));
            };
            next();
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/portfolio',
        component: Portfolio,
        name: 'portfolio',
        beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
            window.onload= function(){
                document.getElementById("WebGL-output").style.opacity = "0";
            };
            next();
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/contacts',
        component: Contacts,
        name: 'contacts',
        beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
            window.onload= function(){
                window.dispatchEvent(new Event("bubbelMoveLeft"));
            };
            next();
        }
    }
];

export const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: routes
});
```

Сама ошибка:

```
Module build failed: TypeError: this.setDynamic is not a function
    at PluginPass.pre (D:\Server\OSPanel\domains\penka\node_modules\babel-plugin-transform-runtime\lib\index.js:31:12)
    at transformFile (D:\Server\OSPanel\domains\penka\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\transformation\index.js:78:27)
    at runSync (D:\Server\OSPanel\domains\penka\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\transformation\index.js:45:3)
    at transformSync (D:\Server\OSPanel\domains\penka\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\transform.js:43:38)
    at Object.transform (D:\Server\OSPanel\domains\penka\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\transform.js:22:38)
    at transpile (D:\Server\OSPanel\domains\penka\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:55:20)
    at D:\Server\OSPanel\domains\penka\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\fs-cache.js:116:18
    at ReadFileContext.callback (D:\Server\OSPanel\domains\penka\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\fs-cache.js:36:21)
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:420:13)
```

Эта ошибка влезает как только я пытаюсь подключить plugin-syntax-dynamic-import. Потому что, как я понял, из коробки mix не поддерживает подгрузку компонентов.

Comment: а где код компонента? что такое `this.setDynamic`? И вообще, мы экстрасенсы, а?

Comment: @n.osennij поправил, извиняюсь...

Comment: Ну блин, какой `window.onload` в `beforeEnter`, с `vue-router` ты же SPA делаешь. Почитай немного доки vue.
Laravel-mix тот еще сборщик, но и его можно настроить - laravel-mix.com